# Per Mozart piano concerto 21

Tags: piano

Explain the infinity symbol w/ sharp above and flat below and sometimes fingering is printed?  Is this similar to a trill of ascending and descending half steps?

Comment: Pretty sure you're describing a [turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn), though if you post a picture showing the musical context you can get a more confident answer and maybe some advice on how best to realize it. The small accidentals and fingerings near it are because the turn causes you to play the neighboring notes of the one on the page; they apply either to the upper or lower neighbor (it would probably be clear from context).